# How to fix httplistener after an exception happens

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, httplistener

I have this HttpListener that receives multiple requests , the problem is that every time an exception happens the listener stops working I tried stoping and restarting the server but it still gets stuck in GetContextAsync.
I am new to asynchronous programming.

```
public class HttpServer{

 public HttpServer(string id)
    {
        try {
            _id= id;
            var prefix = $"http://localhost:39633/queries/{id}/";
            _listener = new HttpListener();
           _listener.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        try {
            while(true ) {
                var context = await _listener.GetContextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);// it stays here
                HandleRequest(context); // handle incoming requests
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

I want the server to keep running , is there a way to do that

Answer (score 1):

Your `catch` block is outside your loop. So every time an exception happens, it leaves the loop. So you just need to invert your `while` and `try` so you can examine the `Exception` (while still inside the loop) and decide if you want to try again or abort.

```
public async Task Start() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            var context = await _listener.GetContextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);// it stays here
            HandleRequest(context); // handle incoming requests
        } catch (HttpListenerException e) {
            // examine e.ErrorCode to see what the problem was and
            // decide to continue or return
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // decide to continue or return
        }
    }
}
```

The [documentation for `HttpListener.GetContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener.getcontext?view=netframework-4.8) (which works the same as `GetContextAsync`) says that when it throws an `HttpListenerException`, that means that:

> A Win32 function call failed. Check the exception's [ErrorCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistenerexception.errorcode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_HttpListenerException_ErrorCode) property to determine the cause of the exception.

In my experience, that is only thrown when you stop the listener intentionally. But maybe something else went wrong. If you tell us the message in the exception, we might be able to help more.

If it helps you, I did write an article with sample code about [creating a basic HttpListener web service](https://www.gabescode.com/dotnet/2018/11/01/basic-HttpListener-web-service.html).

Comment: thank you very much for the quick reply, I have an excel application that loads data from an external source  , when the data is too large the user can cancel the operation , the exception says System.Net.HttpListenerException: 'An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection

Comment: Then, yeah, you should make the change I described and look for that. That specific error should have a specific `ErrorCode` that you can treat differently. Calling `Stop` will also throw an `HttpListenerException`, so you don't want to ignore that one.

Comment: error code is 1229 , I don't know what to do with that :(

Comment: If you want to to continue into the next iteration of the loop, you really don't need to do anything at all. (Except maybe log it if you want) For any error you think should stop the loop, then you `return`.

Comment: which is exactly what I'm doing .. but the http listener stops receiving anymore requests it just stops unless I call start() again . and even if I do that it gets stuck for some readon :(

Comment: Did you make the change I suggested? (Put the `try`/`catch` inside the `while` loop)

Comment: yes I did but I do not want to swallow the exception this exception seems to shutdown the whole listener and nothing is making it work again except restarting the whole application, I googled a lot to find a solution for this exception but I found nothing, I really really need help to solve this issue I have a deadline :(

Comment: Do you mean that when it continues the loop and hits `GetContextAsync()` again, it throws another exception? Can you update your question with your new code?

Comment: @NoorMohammed did you figure it out at the end?